# hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode command is not working

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-16.04, hadoop2

I have installed hadoop 2.7.3 in my ubuntu 16.10. I want to create a multinode cluster and I have done all the steps till formatting the namenode but "hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode command is not working. When I type this command it shows" hadoop-daemon.sh: command not found.

Comment: Are you running the command in the directory that contains the script?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute following command. `sbin/start-dfs.sh` or `sbin/start-yarn.sh`